# Bounding Sobolev Norms *Below*

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, equivalence-relations

Firstly, apologies if this is a duplicate question - I've looked, but can't find this question on SE (or elsewhere online); if it is, please let me know and I'll remove it.

I am trying to bound the Sobolev $s$-norm (for $f \in C^\infty_{per}([-\pi,\pi])$, the set of smooth 2$\pi$-periodic functions)
$$\| f \|_s^2 = \sum_{m \in \Bbb Z}(1+m^2)^s|\hat f(m)|^2$$
**below** by the sup-norm ($\sup|f|$), ie determine $\gamma_s$ such that $\sup|f| \le \gamma_s \|f\|_s$. Firstly, I am trying to do the case $s=1$, then determine whether it's true for general $s$. 
I *guess* that it is not true for general $s$, as the next part of the question of the question asks to generalise the statement to an $n$-variable function, and then determine $\sigma(n)$ such that it is true if and only if $s > \sigma(n)$.

Also, similarly, trying to find $C_s > 0$ such that $\|u(t,\cdot)\|_s \le C_s \|u(0,\cdot)\|_0$, where $u(t,x)$ satisfies the heat equation $\partial_t u = \partial^2_x u$.

(I have a formula for $\|f\|_s$ in terms of $f$ and its derivatives.)

Any help would be most appreciated as I'm pretty stuck!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your definition of $||f||_s$ is wrong: the square root on the right-hand side is missing. Now, if we use the correct definition
$$
 ||f||_s=\sqrt{\sum_m(1+m^2)^s|\hat f(m)|^2},
$$
then everything is pretty straightforward:
$$
\sup_x|f(x)|=\sup_x\left|\sum_m\hat f(m)e^{imx}\right|\le\sum_m|\hat f(m)|=\sum_m |\hat f(m)|(1+m^2)^{s/2}(1+m^2)^{-s/2}
$$
(by Cauchy-Schwarz)
$$
\le\sqrt{\sum_m |\hat f(m)|^2(1+m^2)^{s}}\sqrt{\sum_m (1+m^2)^{-s} },
$$
provided that
$$
 \gamma_s:=\sqrt{\sum_m (1+m^2)^{-s} }<\infty,
$$
which is true if and only if $s>\sigma(1):=1/2$.

In the $n$-dimensional case we have
$$
 \gamma_s:=\sqrt{\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^n} (1+m^2)^{-s} }\equiv
\sqrt{\sum_{m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n\in \mathbb{Z}} (1+m_1^2+m_2^2+\dots+ m_n^2)^{-s} }<\infty 
$$
for $s>\sigma(n):=n/2$.

If $\hat u(t,m)$ are the Fourier coefficients of the solution $u(x,t)$ of the heat equation at time $t$, then 
$$
 \hat u(t,m)=e^{-m^2t}\hat u(0,m).
$$
This will help you to answer your last question yourself.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, typo with missing the square on the left. When I was trying to work it out, I did of course have the square, but couldn't do it (so not straightforward for me! :P). I understand how you've done it though, thank you. It's easy if you know/spot the trick of multiplying by
$$(1+m^2)^{s/2} (1+m^2)^{-s/2} = 1$$
but I didn't spot this trick, so was pretty stuck!

Comment: Oh, and for the last bit, I had the solution in terms of the Fourier transforms (fairly easy to obtain), but I couldn't get any further; I couldn't get it in terms of the $0$-norm (ie, I could get $t=0$, but not $s=0$).